# FITS BinTableHDU data format (TFORM) conversion to numpy dtype

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I'm looking for Python code to convert a FITS TFORM data format (such as 64A or I10 or D12) to a numpy dtype. The numpy format_parser won't do it. I can't believe that no one has solved this before, e.g. TOPCAT clearly does it but in java. However, I cannot find any references to conversion in this direction in Python. Can anyone help?

I've googled and searched and RTFM'd but no success.

Comment: Does the [AstroPy Table](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/unified.html#table-io-fits) routines meet your needs ? They can directly read FITS Binary table data and it uses numpy under the hood so the columns come out as numpy arrays of the appropriate type